# assigning boolean values into boolean variables

Tags: c++, boolean

```
int x = 5;    
bool t = ((x % 3) && (x % 4));
```

when I try this code in visual studio, I get the value `true` for variable `t`. How this code is working?

Comment: Please get informed regarding modulo and logical and (you should delete this question (too late))

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have the && operator, which compares two values and returns a boolean, so t will b a boolean. Secondly, in C++, every value other than 0 will evaluate to true, so `x % 3`, which evaluates to `2` will return true, then `x % 4`, which evaluates to `1` will also return true.

So in the end you have

```
bool t = (x % 3) && (x % 4);
```

which equals

```
bool t = 2 && 1;
```

which equals

```
bool t = true && true;
```

which equals

```
bool t = true;
```

Comment: um, && doesn't compare two values! also, the conversion to bool happens *after* the &&, as I understand things.

Comment: In a sense it does, it's a logical AND, which basically compares two boolean values, it's true that on an assembly level comparison and logical AND are different, however, conceptually a comparison of booleans and a logical AND are not so different.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `%` returns the remainder after division (modulo) and `true` is any value that is not 0.

```
5 % 3 == 2
5 % 4 == 1
2 && 1 == true && true == true
```

Answer (score 0):

All nonzero values are considered as true for logical operations like AND(&&) and OR(||)

x%3 -s a module operation returned value 2,
x%4  returns 1

2 && 1   is equal to true && true , which is equal to true.

All non zero value assignment to a bool typed variable is considered as true or 1 and all zero value assignment considered as false or 0.

Answer (score -1):

you can just do:

> bool t=(x% 3!=0) && (x% 4!=0);

Comment: *Why* would one do this and what difference does it make?

Comment: I think that, if I use like ' bool t=(x% 3!=0) && (x% 4!=0); ' the bool is not meaning.

Comment: As c++ introduced the BOOL type for boolean variables which could be either true or false, then you _italic_ might use explicit compare expressions that returns boolean results, like the one I've written.

But if you're already used to C style, you could still go on it and use (other than zero is true) style in your conditions.